# Can I use Fubini's theorem on this function?

Tags: calculus

Given function is $f(x,y)=\sin(x)e^{-xt}$. Problem says "use" Fubini's theorem and the fact that $\int_0^\infty e^{-xt} dt=\frac{1}{x}$ to prove that $$\lim\limits_{A\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^A \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

So I used Fubini without doubt but thus the integral of $|f(x,y)|$ does not seem to be $<\infty$. I hope my calculation is wrong. please help.

Comment: Please fix the typos and show us your approach.

Comment: You use Fubini's theorem for an arbitrary but fixed finite $A$.

Comment: Is there typos? Sorry I can find...

Comment: Should be $e^{-xt}$ rather than $E^{-xt}$, and the limit is wrong, it's $\frac{\pi}{2}$ actually.

Comment: 1. since $|\sin(x)e^{-xt}|\le e^{-xt}$, I tried to calculate this with respect to x first (0 to infinity) than I gives me integration of 1/x over 0 to A<infinity but, than I have $\log(0)$ which is -infinity. So I tried to integrate with respec to t first but it also have 1/t term.

Answer (score 2):

For each $A>0$, $e^{-xt}$ is integrable for $0\leq x\leq A$, $0\leq t$. So you can apply Fubini:
$$
\int_0^A\frac{\sin x}x\,dx=\int_0^A\int_0^\infty e^{-xt}\,\sin x \,dt dx=\int_0^A\int_0^\infty e^{-xt}\,\sin x \,dx dt\\
=\int_0^\infty\left[\frac 1{1+t^2}-\frac{e^{-tA}}{t^2+1}(t\cos A+\sin A)\right]\,dt\\
=\frac\pi2-\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-tA}}{t^2+1}(t\cos A+\sin A)\,dt.
$$
As 
$$
\left|\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-tA}}{t^2+1}(t\cos A+\sin A)\,dt\right|\leq2\int_0^\infty e^{-tA}\,dt=\frac2A\to0,
$$
we get 
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}x\,dx=\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_0^A\frac{\sin x}x\,dx=\frac\pi2.
$$